# angular-laravel create users gives a query exception

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to create new users in a basic laravel-angularjs app. I'm getting a 500 server error and upon looking further into it there's a query exception. I'm passing a text value for the password which is hashed. Is the error because of this?

**angular controller:**

```
user.saveUsers({
          "first_name":um.firstName,
          "last_name":um.lastName,
          "admin":um.admin,
          "email":um.email,
          "password":um.password
        }).then(function(success) {

          console.log(success);
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

**the laravel controller:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $data = Request::all();

        $users = new User();

        $users->fill($data);

        $users->save();
    }
```

**users.php:**

```
 protected $fillable = ['first_name','last_name','admin', 'email', 'password'];
 protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
```

**Table Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "first_name" varchar not null, "last_name" varchar not null, "admin" tinyint not null, "email" varchar not null, "password" varchar not null, "remember_token" varchar null, "created_at" datetime not null, "updated_at" datetime not null)
```

Comment: What's the content of the query exception? Can you check your logs?

Comment: `QueryException in Connection.php line 636:? �minate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse">AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))?
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124`